# dismissViewControllerAnimated shows a white screen

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I got a ViewController named viewControllerA which presents ViewControllerB with this common code:

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
[self presentViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES completion:nil];
```

viewControllerB is a UITabbarController but when calling

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

from one of the TabbarControllers ViewControllers (say page 2) I just get a white screen. I was expecting to see viewControllerA but instead I just see an empty screen.

also

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[self presentingViewController] class]);
```

logs viewControllerA.

Does anybody know why I get a empty white screen instead of viewControllerA?

**EDIT**
I put a breakpoint on viewDidAppear in viewControllerA and it does break there when calling dismissViewControllerAnimated. But how is it possible that it only shows a white screen?

Also I think you should know that viewControllerA's layout is created programatically. viewControllerB is created much later and in the meantime we decided to use a storyboard so viewControllerB's layout is created with storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove your self (in viewcontrollerB)
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Answer (score -1):

If you present `viewControllerB` from `viewControllerA` using

```
[self presentViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you should probably call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in the  `viewControllerA`, but not from one of the of the pages of your `TabBarViewController`.

Comment: So you're saying I should do: [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Sadly that shows a white screen as well.

Comment: A -> B - > Page 2, it must be called in A, make some delegate or move back correctly through the viewcontrollers hierarchy.

Comment: but presentingViewController is A right? In the meantime ill type some code that moves back to A

Comment: No, bacause Page 2 is not presented in A directly.

Comment: Thanks for that dirty check. Did what you said but with the same result. Put a breakpoint on pop and it indeed gets called from Page 2 but its still a white screen.

Comment: Than it is something is wrong with storyboard or your code, some ViewController is getting released. Difficult to say